# Character texture is missing parts when rendering at an angle

Tags: c, opengl

This is my first program using OpenGL. I wrote a very simple text module to write to the screen. It loads the character texture and renders it.

I know I should have a big texture with all characters, but this time I used one 64x64 texture for each character.

It works fine when the camera is not at an angle. But as soon as I apply transformations, some characters are not rendered correctly. Here's what happens:

[image]

I'm using this code to render the text:

```
typedef struct {
    Renderable renderable;
    const char *buffer;
    float r, g, b;
    float x, y, z;
    float x_scale, y_scale; 
} Text;

static bool render(void *text_ptr, game_clock_t time)
{
    Text *text = text_ptr;
    float position = text->x;

    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);    
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; text->buffer[i] != '\0'; ++i){  
        glColor3f(text->r, text->g, text->b);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[text->buffer[i]].id);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);      
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(position, text->y, -text->z);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(position + text->x_scale, text->y, -text->z);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(position + text->x_scale, text->y + text->y_scale, -text->z);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(position, text->y + text->y_scale, -text->z);
        glEnd();

        position += (float)36/64 * text->x_scale;
    }       

    return false;
}
```

And the transformations I'm using throughout the whole game:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(45, 16.f / 9.f, 1, 128);
gluLookAt(15, 8, 15, 5, 5, -30 / 2, 0, 1, 0);
glTranslatef(-5, 2, 0);
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: Do not put everything into your projection matrix. Change your matrix mode to `GL_MODELVIEW` after `gluPerspective (...)` and call `glLoadIdentity (...)`.

Comment: Also, rather than putting the transformation into each vertex manually, you should probably set your modelview matrix with the transform, and then draw each character with the same 4 vertices.

Comment: Do you have depth testing turned on? (That is, have you called `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);`? If so, are you clearing the depth buffer before drawing by calling `glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT|GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`?

Comment: @user1118321 Yes, depth testing is turned on, it's being cleared once per frame.

Comment: also, make sure you are requesting a context with a depth buffer, in glut it would be glutInitDeviceMode( GLUT_DEPTH )

Comment: Is the text UTF16? You might be drawing 2 times for each letter and the fist is blank then overwritten by a char (works when looking up front and having z test 'less'). Thus you see z-buffer fighting.